# Issue with .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a CMS where the styles and formatting for a given page are dynamically generated depending on the type of page (general, member, download,etc.). In the past I have used the following .htaccess to identify the page type:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^general/(.*)$ general.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which works fine but required me to create a rendering page for each page type... general.php, member.php, download.php, etc.

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO IS...

Through .htaccess have a wild card to identify the page type to have all pages render from a single [page.php] file so that the page types can be created on the fly without have to create a rendering page for each page type.

I am having an issue with a $ sign showing up in my results. I only know enough about .htaccess to be dangerous.

THIS IS MY TEST PHP

```
<?php

$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];

echo $type.'<br>'.$title;

?>
```

THIS URL:

http://my-site.com/general/this-is-a-general-page

WITH THE .HTACCESS REWRITE RULE SET AS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ temp.php?type=$1$&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

PRODUCES:

```
general$
this-is-a-general-page
```

I can't figure out why the $ is at the end of the page type. I have also tried removing the $:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) temp.php?type=$1$&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ temp.php?type=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You had a stray `$` after `$1` in your rule.

**PS:** I have also tweaked your regex a little to make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @anubhava... worked great. I'll give you the check when the script allows... really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Its amazing what your eyes become blinded... i stared at reread that line of code numerous times and never noticed the extra $... thanks for the tweak as well

Comment: Yes I know sometimes it happens to all of us.. after spending hours we figure out one missing `$` or `%` in scripts.